# How to select row based on column value grouped by distinct pairs?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following info in my database:

```
 TO | FROM |    DATE   |  PRICE
AAA |  BBB | 12/3/2012 |  $100
AAA |  CCC | 12/3/2010 |  $200
AAA |  BBB | 10/3/2010 |  $450
BBB |  CCC | 09/7/2010 |  $270
BBB |  AAA | 06/9/2011 |  $130
AAA |  CCC | 12/3/2013 |  $176
```

I want to write a query (or a LINQ expression preferably) that selects the most recent TO-FROM pairs, so based on the table above I want the following data returned in my query:

```
 TO | FROM |    DATE   |  PRICE
AAA |  BBB | 12/3/2012 |  $100
BBB |  CCC | 09/7/2010 |  $270
BBB |  AAA | 06/9/2011 |  $130
AAA |  CCC | 12/3/2013 |  $176
```

What is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned your RDBMS, the query below works on most RDBMS

```
SELECT a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT To, FROM, MAX(DATE) maxDate
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY To, FROM
        ) b ON a.To = b.To AND
                a.FROM = b.FROM AND
                a.DATE = b.maxDATE
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3b21/2)

but if you're RDBMS supports `CTE` and `WINDOWS FUNCTION`

```
WITH latestRecord AS
(
SELECT [To], [FROM], DATE, Price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY [TO], [FROM] ORDER BY date DESC) rn
FROM tableName
)
SELECT [To], [FROM], DATE, Price
FROM latestRecord
WHERE rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3b21/11)

or `WINDOWS FUNCTION ONLY`

```
SELECT [To], [FROM], DATE, Price
FROM 
(
    SELECT [To], [FROM], DATE, Price,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY [TO],[FROM] ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM tableName
) s
WHERE rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3b21/9)

One more thing to point out, `TO` and `FROM` are somewhat Reserved Keywords, they must be escaped with a escaped char which depends on the `RDBMS` you are using.

Comment: Thanks. I came up with the same thing, I just wasn't sure if there was an easier way